# moment.js fromNow() returning strange results

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

In my web application I am saving dates to the database in this format,

> 2015-07-02 17:28:47

This translates to the 2nd July 2015 17:28:47

I am then using moment.js to turn that into something like `10 minutes ago` however at the moment all dates being returned as `in 8 days` here is the code I am using,

`moment(notification.created_at, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').fromNow()`

Comment: got a demo we can look at?

Comment: works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/Mzqj4/183/ what is your system clock set too?

Comment: I bet that date time you are looking at in the database has a different format when it sent over the wire to the client.

Comment: Yeah try `console.log(notification.created_at);` what is the value?